# How to create req.query.parameter?

Tags: reactjs, express

I don't how to do it, please help the kidding develop (T_T).

It shows "undefined" when I'm executing:

```
router.get("/filter-report/", verifyToken, (req, res) => {
    queries.report_table
    .Filter_leave() 
    .then(requests => {
      let leavetype = req.query.request_category;
      let depart = req.query.department;
      let fname = req.query.first_name;
      let obj = {filter: leavetype + ''+ depart+''+fname}
      console.log(obj);
      res.json(obj);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL should look like `/filter-report?request_category=category&department=dev&first_name=test`

but I think the error is in line 2, `queries` is not defined/initialized

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Vinil's answer. Queries can be accessed from req. It is an Object. So if your url looks like this:

```
/filter-report?request_category=category&department=dev&first_name=test
```

Then your query object will be looking like this:

```
{
  request_category: category,
  department: dev,
  first_name: test
}
```

And you can access that query as usual using `req.query.request_category`, etc.